# Key combination to delete without copying to clipboard/register ? (General)

Tags: key-bindings, command, selection

What's the command/option/keys/function that performs a delete on a selection (in visual mode) without copying the selection to clipboard/register? I.e I don't want to use `d` or `x` as they will delete but also copy to clipboard/register.

Here's what I have currently:

`vnoremap <BS> xi`

...but right now it just deletes and copies the selection.

Comment: It looks like this may be the answer you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register

Comment: Oh great thanks ! `"_d` worked.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!